# Unban my account

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

I learned my lesson how to participate in Stack Overflow. I have started to answer several questions honestly, and will do so in the future.

I am not going to make another fake account, and would like to keep the current one, because I sincerely want to get involved.

Is there a way to unban my account? I've searched the FAQ and Meta Stack Overflow, but no luck.

Comment: Your account is not currently suspended

Comment: Yay! Welcome back! Thanks for being honest.

Comment: Please do the same to me Mich

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I unblocked you. The answer block came because three of your answers were promoting a library you wrote (http://www.tog2html.com) without clearly stating you are the creator of the library. They attracted spam flags and got deleted.

This is seen as particularly problematic if they happen to be among your first answers on the site.

Please be extra careful promoting your work and libraries on the site, make sure you properly attribute it to yourself and make sure the question really calls for it.

Comment: And even if your library does do something wonderful, don't go trawling through old questions looking for ones where you can suggest its use, even if you do put the correct attribution - that is still spam.

Comment: Hello, I've also just got banned for a similar reason. I wouldn't mind knowing why, or how to get this ban reversed. I am a legitamate contributor to StackOverflow and my answers are always helpful, constructive and to the point. However, I linked to two external libraries (one which I have developed, another I have not) in multiple posts and now my account is suspended. Please can someone review my posts and advise on what I should do to correct this. I see people linking all the time to exeternal libs, even their own, so didn't see a problem so long as it is a genuine response to questions.

Comment: @AndrewBurnett-Thompson you are not blocked at the moment